# Error "The parameter is incorrect" while signing C# VSTO manifest

Tags: c#, certificate, vsto

I bought from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) '[Class 2 validation](https://www.startssl.com/?app=2)'. Then I successfully created the Object Code Signing Certificate (PFX) and successfully imported my certificate into Visual Studio 2010.

[Imported certificate in VS 2010 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80507/signing/configuration.PNG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80507/signing/configuration.PNG)

When I try to sign the VSTO Manifest (for PowerPoint Add-In ClickOnce setup), I get this error:

```
An error occured while signing: The parameter is incorrect.
```

[Signing error http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80507/signing/error.PNG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80507/signing/error.PNG)

I spoke with StartSSL and their certificate would not have a problem with this.

Comment: when you run certmgr.msc do you see star com class 2 in trusted root CA?

Comment: Yes, I see Start Com as trusted CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify StartSSL timestamp server, the certificate (and ClickOnce manifest signing) works without problems.